# nested exception could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, exception, intellij-idea, nested

I get a problem in postman about hibernate. can you help me?

I don`t know what is the problem, as you can see here are my codes. I got this error in IntelliJ idea ERROR: column "username" is of type integer, but expression is of type character varying.
and there is part of my codes.

```
var id: Long = 0,
var username: String = "",
var password: String = ""
```

How can it be possible when my column is string?
thank you very much.

Comment: Please include your MySQL query.  The error message is self-explanatory enough.

Comment: I dont know why username column in integer while i put it string. can you guide me?